# NFS server optimization for maximum performance

Tags: mount, performance, nfs

I'm looking for maximum of performance for a NFS mount.

I'm on local network, it could be completely unsecured, the performance is the most important in my case.

What I already found :

In `/etc/export` I've defined *async* mode, and it already helped a lot.

In `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` I've found following variables, which could potentially increase the performance :

```
# Number of servers to start up
RPCNFSDCOUNT=8
# Runtime priority of server (see nice(1))
RPCNFSDPRIORITY=0
# Options for rpc.mountd.
RPCMOUNTDOPTS=--manage-gids
```

The `NFS` server is on Linux Mint, and the client, which mount remote partition is Debian 6.

If there are any recommendation for maximum performance of NFS server ?

Should I change the RPCNFSDPRIORITY ?

If there are any other parameters, which could boost NFS server ?

Client actually mounts the NFS partition with following configuration :

```
server:/remotepath    /localpath    nfs4 rw,intr,hard,noatime,rsize=32768,wsize=32768 0 0
```

Is that optimal mounting options for NFS v4 share ?

Comment: You mentioned you don't care if it's unsecure, then try to go with nfs v3. but if you find something more concrete I would love to know as well.

Comment: If I understand good, v4 is more performant, than v3, at least it's mentionned at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System

Answer (score 3):

You can modify `timeo` and `retrans` options while mounting.  For example:

```
mount 192.168.0.102:/data /mnt -o timeo=5,retrans=4
```

this affects the number of retry attempts made by the client to the server in case of a delayed response from the server or sometimes no response from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Don't hardcode rsize and wsize on modern Linux, they are automagically optimized and will get bigger than your example.